# How to create a migration without "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly" problem?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration, dbcontext

I am trying to create a migration in an ASP.NET Core Web Application, but when I try to do it, the package manager console returns a warning and an error:

Warning: "A version of Entity Framework older than 6.3 is also installed. The newer tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' for the older version."

Error: "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'MyProjectName'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration)."

After doing some research I have found that a common problem is that the default project chosen in the package manager is not correct; but this is not my case, since it only gives me one option, and it is the project with which I am working.
I have also found that a current solution is to enable the migrations with the "Enable-Migrations" command, but when I try to do this, it gives me the same warning and another error:

error: No context type was found in the assembly 'MyProjectName'.

I have also tried it the "enable-migraitons" command in a different way, "enable-migrations -contexttypename MyDBContextName", but this gives me another error:

error: The context type 'MyDBContextName' was not found in the assembly 'MyProjectName'.

But I actually have the following class:

```
    public class MyDBContextName: IdentityDbContext<UserModel>
    {
        public MyDBContextName(DbContextOptions<MyDBContextName> options) : base(options)
        { 
        }
    }
```

And I have this in my startup/configure services class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDBContextName>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));

    services.AddIdentity<UserModel, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDBContextName>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Lastly, [image: this] is a picture of my NuGet packages:

Any Idea of what may be causing these errors?
Thank you so much for your time, if you need more information I will provide it to you ass soon as I see your request. Have a good day. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't know what caused those errors, but after some changes I can now create migrations. Here are the 3 changes that I made:

1. I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
2. I changed

`services.AddDbContext<MyDBContextName>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));`

for

`services.AddDbContext<MyDBContextName>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

3. Finally, in my app.setting.json I changed

```
"connectionStrings": 
{
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=MyName;Initial Catalog=PracticaApiSecurity;Integrated Security=True"
},
```

for

```
  "connectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnections": "Data Source=MyName;Initial Catalog=PracticaApiSecurity;Integrated Security=True"
  },
```

changed connection for connectionS

Comment: Selecting the right project in the packet manager console solved the problem for me! 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402331/package-manager-console-add-migration-command-not-working

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of this error by closing my instance of Visual Studio 2019 and reopening it.

Answer (score 1):

Running:
PM> EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration

Worked for me:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK2wX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the right project in the packet manager console solved the problem.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Installing installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had everything configured and setup correctly so none of these suggestions worked. I took a bit more research to discover that my issue was that I also had the EntityFrameWork package installed along with EntityFrameWorkCore. I was using the later for some older functions I had in my Library which executed SqlCommand.

Installing both packages completely scrubbed my project so I ended up having to completely reset my EntityFramework Migrations by following this suggestion:
[Reset Entity Framework](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate)